# escaping space in shell script path

Tags: terminal, script

I have tried both methods of escaping the space in the Path in the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
PGHOME="/Applications/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/SharedSupport"
$PGHOME/psql --username postgres -c "drop database $1"
```

I've also tried changing line 2 to:

```
PGHOME=/Applications/pgAdmin\ 4.app/Contents/SharedSupport
```

In *both* cases I get the script error:

> ./pg10-restoreDb.sh: line 3: /Applications/pgAdmin: No such file or directory

From the shell, I can execute `/Applications/pgAdmin\ 4.app/Contents/SharedSupport/psql` no problem

What could be causing this error?

Comment: In the future probably more appropriate to ask on stackoverflow and tag with bash since bash is not Apple-specific, but glad you got an answer pretty quickly here :)

Comment: The question is perfectly on-topic here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either quote or escape the space when you define the variable, but then you must also double-quote it when you use it:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
PGHOME="/Applications/pgAdmin 4.app/Contents/SharedSupport"
"$PGHOME/psql" --username postgres -c "drop database $1"
^            ^
|            |
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved MY issue too (after I'd already spent 15 min on it).